# Is there a way to simulate a "low level" trackpad click with python?

Tags: macos, input

I'm on a mac using Universal Control (UC) which allows you to share a mouse/keyboard between two macs.

The way UC currently works is that when you move the mouse pointer to computer #2, keyboard input remains with computer #1 until you click on computer #2 with the track pad to give the computer focus.

After figuring out a hack to get the mouse pointer over to computer #2 with a script, I am trying to automate this click on computer #2 to get computer #2 keyboard control without me having to physically click the trackpad:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, KeyCode
import pyautogui
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateMouseEvent, kCGEventMouseMoved, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, kCGEventLeftMouseUp, kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState, kCGMouseButtonLeft, CGEventPost, kCGHIDEventTap


screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

# Calculate the center coordinates
center_x = screen_width // 2
center_y = screen_height // 2

# print the center coordinates
print(center_x, center_y)

# find the center of the screen and move to it
pyautogui.moveTo(center_x, center_y)
my_move = 400
pyautogui.moveTo(center_x, center_y + my_move)

def simulate_trackpad_click(x, y):
    # Move the cursor to the desired position
    event_move = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, kCGEventMouseMoved, (x, y), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
    CGEventPost(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState, event_move)

    # Simulate left mouse button down
    event_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, (x, y), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
    CGEventPost(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState, event_down)

    # Simulate left mouse button up
    event_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, kCGEventLeftMouseUp, (x, y), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
    CGEventPost(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState, event_up)

# Usage
simulate_trackpad_click(center_x - 200, center_y + my_move)
```

Even though the clicks are registering on the second computer, (I can see the mouse pointer change it's icon to reflect it's in a text field), the second computer still does not get focus. I'm thinking because the trackpad click so not low level enough to register with Universal Control.

Any possible way to pull this off with python?

Comment: For starters, you don't need to move the mouse to the center of the screen in order to click. You can just do: `pyautogui.click(center_x, center_y + 400)`, using `CGEventPost` is unecessary, `pyautogui` is easier, and is probably more reliable.